# How can I decorate parent with DataAnnotations, but validate for child property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, client-side

Let's say I have a CustomField class as follow

```
public class CustomField
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have multiple ViewModel class, each one is for another type of form

```
public class FirstViewModel
{
    public CustomField Title { get; set; }
}

public class SecondViewModel
{
    public CustomField Subject { get; set; }
}
```

How can I put data annotation on child property of ViewModel, but actually validate for child property of CustomField?

For example, I can decorate Title and Subject with different set of data annotation, and it will validate the Value property of CustomField based on the data annotation

```
public class FirstViewModel
{
    [CustomFieldStringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "string length must between 2 and 20")]
    public CustomField Title { get; set; }
}

public class SecondViewModel
{
    [CustomFieldStringLength(30, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "string length must between 2 and 30")]
    public CustomField Subject { get; set; }
}
```

What I have tried:

Override the StringLengthAttribute, which will work on server side

```
public class CustomFieldStringLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
    public CustomFieldStringLengthAttribute(int maximumLength) : base(maximumLength)
    {
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        CustomFieldValue customFieldValue = (CustomFieldValue)value;
        return base.IsValid(customFieldValue.Value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

Get default Adapter to generate correct client side validator

```
public class CustomFieldStringLengthAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<CustomFieldStringLengthAttribute>
{
    public CustomFieldStringLengthAdapter(
        ModelMetadata metadata,
        ControllerContext context,
        CustomFieldStringLengthAttribute attribute) : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    {
        return new[] { new ModelClientValidationStringLengthRule(ErrorMessage, Attribute.MinimumLength, Attribute.MaximumLength) };
    }
}

// Register in Global.asax.cs Application_Start

DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(CustomFieldStringLengthAttribute), typeof(CustomFieldStringLengthAdapter));
```

For client-side, it's still generate the validation rules for the CustomField, not the Value of it.

Is this the correct approach?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot. Validation only applies to properties, not complex objects, and the `ValidationContext ` applies only to the model. You need to create separate'child' view models with different validation attributes.

Comment: An alternative is to write your own conditional validation attribute so that the string length is based on the value of another property within the model, for example `CustomField` would contain a property (say) `int ValueLength` and your would set that to 20 in `FirstViewModel` and 30 in `SecondViewModel`

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you have any example for doing that?

Comment: I would start by reading [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)